# Mixing versions can lead runtime crashes

Tags: java, compiler-errors, mixing

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) There are some
>   combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion)

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.group.com.pdftest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What a lovely story

Comment: I found the answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009286/gradle-mixing-versions-27-1-1-and-26-1-0