# Gradle mixing versions 27.1.1 and 26.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting an error in my app-level build.gradle where on the first support library I am using, it tells me that all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification and that it's found versions 27.1.1 and 26.0.2.  In my app-level build.gradle, there is no line using 26.1.0.  Also, all `compile` statements have been changed to `implementation`, the `compileSdkVersion` is 27 and the `targetSdkVersion` is 27.  To attempt to find the culprit, I ran:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
```

And got the following output:

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debugAndroidTest
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.1
|    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[15.0.0] -> 15.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
+--- com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.5.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:disklrucache:4.5.0
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.5.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0
+--- me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.1.4
+--- com.github.fiskurgit:ChipCloud:3.0.5
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Here it shows that `com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0` in `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0` is using 26.1.0 but in the drilldown it has `-> 27.1.1 (*)` which I'm assuming means that it's using 27.1.1 instead?  I'm getting the same thing from `com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0` in play-services.  What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The line

```
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0
```

does not have a `-> 27.1.1` at the end of it, which means it is not getting automatically upgraded to `27.1.1` (it shows up under the transitive dependencies because those transitive dependencies **are** being automatically upgraded).

You can force it to use the `27.1.1` version by manually adding that dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the mismatching version number (26.1.0) in app.iml file and can add those dependencies in app level build.gradle, forcing to use latest version (27.1.1 in this case)