# com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 mismatch with media-compat:25.2.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

In my project dependencies `android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` but its clashing with `support-media-compat: 25.2.0`. i tried to slove it by changing appcompat-v7:25.+ , 25.2.0 and others but its not fixed. Even i don't find media-compat in gradle or anywhere.

Please help me to fix it. Now I can't run my project on AVD or USB connected phone.
[image: Here is my android studio interface]

[[image: When i rebuild my project its says All fine but when i tried to run the project it gives some error[2]]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem when adding `Firebase invites`. I solved by adding this to dependencies, following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009286/gradle-mixing-versions-27-1-1-and-26-1-0).

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

According to the post, the error is misguiding. The problem is not a dependency conflict but the lack of the dependency package. But i am not sure of this interpretation, anyway, it works.

Comment: yes it works... # lack of the dependency package # this is correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly a lib you are using might depend on it. Check your dependency tree using the gradle task `app:dependencies`.

More info can be found in this answer [Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Please describe.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to update your Google Services to the latest version.
Change the version in App gradle.

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```